# После подключения кастомного домена к странице на gh pages браузер отображает пустую страницу

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

Всем привет. Не получается подключить кастомный домен к веб-странице, которая хостится на **gh pages**. После подключения в браузере просто пустая страница: https://www.sovietboxers.com

**Дано:**

Проект:  SPA на Vue, хостится на gh pages: https://github.com/pazukdev/sovietboxers/tree/gh-pages

Настройки DNS сделал по гайду своего доменного регистратора: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages :

```
- A record for @ pointing to 185.199.108.153
- A record for @ pointing to 185.199.109.153
- A record for @ pointing to 185.199.110.153
- A record for @ pointing to 185.199.111.153
- CNAME record for www pointing to pazukdev.github.io.
```

Деплою в ветку gh-pages с помощью распространенного в интернетах скрипта: https://github.com/pazukdev/sovietboxers/blob/master/deploy.sh

В скрипте CNAME указал: https://github.com/pazukdev/sovietboxers/blob/a8d9a63ee090283b05de644d3a34ed245dbf8d3c/deploy.sh#L13

В настройках проекта  на **github** Custom domain указал: *www.sovietboxers.com*

**Результат:**
 
Белая страница в браузере. Хотя до подключения кастомного домена все было нормально. Значит с подключением я что-то я делаю не так..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. При деплое без использования кастомного домена переменная publicPath в vue.config.js для билдов разработки и продакшена принимает разное значение:

```
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/my-project/' : '/'
```

При подключении кастомного домена она должна принимать одно значение:

```
publicPath: './'
```

Тогда index.html генерируется с правильными путями к скриптам и стилям. А именно в том, что не находились файлы стилей и ресурсов и была причина пустой белой страницы при подключении кастомного домена.